# Style controls on iOS 6 with layers are wrong? (From iOS7)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, layer

I'm creating an app and I'm styling some controls like text fields and buttons with layers (for example changing the border color and thickness),  or simply by changing the background color of the control from the Interface Builder.

On iOS 7 it's all working good, but when I run the application on iOS 6 (simulator) I see old style controls plus borders of the layer.

The two versions were running both with the iOS 6.1 SDK.

Here is the screen of what is happening: (I can't post images for the reputation on SO)

[image]

EDIT:

The code for the textfields i use is this:

```
   UITextField* textField = (UITextField*) aView;
   textField.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
   textField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
   textField.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

And for the "Login" button i simply changed the background color in the IB.

Comment: please post the code you wrote for this so we can find what's wrong.

Comment: Edited with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the border of the textFields, set the `borderStyle` to none:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

As for the Login button, don't forget to set the button's type to Custom in IB.

[image]

Tell me if that works.

Comment: Thank you, that worked but only one thing... in the textfield the text is attached on the left border of the field. Like if it have no padding on the left. How i can solve this problem?